# FastAPI finds my JSON array of objects an invalid list

Tags: python, json, fastapi, starlette

I'm using FastAPI and I'm trying to send a JSON array of JSON objects to my post endpoint, in the body.
My endpoint is defined as:

```py
@router.post("/create_mails")
def create_mails(notas: List[schemas.Nota], db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
```

My body in Postman looks like:

```json
{
    "notas": [{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"},
              {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"}]
}
```

However, I keep getting the 422 unprocessable entity error from FastAPI, with the error detail:
*value is not a valid list*

I also tested it with a modified endpoint:

```py
@router.post("/create_mails")
def create_mails(notas: List[str] = Body([]), db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
```

and with a simple string array, but the same error is returned.

Am I missing FastAPI's definition of a valid list?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your POST method parameter needs to model the entire request body, which is indeed a single object, and not a list.
To match the body you're trying to send, you'd need something like:

```
class NotaList(BaseModel):
    notas: List[Nota]
```

and then:

```
def create_mails(body: schemas.NotaList)
```

Note that the parameter name in your function is *not* part of the data model, it just represents the "top-level" body object. I've renamed it to `body` here to clarify that. The `notas` in the request body will get assigned to the `notas` member of the class, so inside your method you'll access things like (for example):

```
for nota in body.notas:
    # do stuff
```

Comment: I tried this with class:
`class NotaList(BaseModel):
    list: List[schemas.Nota]`
, and tested with data:
`{
    "notas": {"list": [{"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"},
              {"a":"1","b":"2","c":"3","d":"4"}]}
}`

But I get the error: `{"detail":[{"loc":["body","list"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}`

Comment: @Simon if your `NotaList` class attribute is named `list` then the post variable also has to be `"list`" -- why are you wrapping it in an extra `"notas"` ?

Comment: Ahh thanks this was my mistake! I thought it had to be in an extra "notas" because my method parameter was called like that. But using only list is the trick!

Comment: Your method parameter's name is only relevant to your own code, and it represents the "nameless" _top-level_ dictionary in the POST.